# numpy one dimensional array incase of list of different length

Tags: numpy

First of all i really sorry if i am posting a very silly question. I am very new to Numpy.

Question:

Scenario 1 :

```
import numpy as np
data=[1,2,3,4]
type(data)
array=np.array(data)
array
array.ndim
array.shape
```

OUTPUT:

```
array
Out[63]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

array.ndim
Out[64]: 1

array.shape
Out[65]: (4,)
```

> > My question is what is the meaning of (4,). Does it mean it a single row having 4 element. Can we say it is row vector which has one row and 4 column. 
> >     If yes then it is creating confusion in the second scenario

Scenario 2 :

```
data1 =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
array1 =np.array(data)
array1 =array1=np.array(data1) 
array1
array1.ndim
array1.shape
```

OUTPUT:

```
array1
Out[67]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]], dtype=object)
array1.ndim
Out[68]: 1
array1.shape
Out[69]: (2,)
```

Here my question is the answer of array1.shape should be (7,) as the dimension is 1. 
I want to know here , it is how many rows and how many column. Also why the output is (2,)

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list of numbers:

```
In [166]: data = [1,2,3,4]
```

`arr` is 1 dimensional array made from that list - with 4 elements

```
In [167]: arr = np.array(data)
In [168]: arr
Out[168]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
In [169]: arr.ndim
Out[169]: 1
In [170]: arr.shape
Out[170]: (4,)
```

Note that the display of `arr` has the same `[]` as the original list.

When talking about 1d arrays, don't try to use `row` and `column` ideas.  You did not start with a list of lists, and the array does not have rows.  It is 1d.

(4,) is Python notation for a single element tuple.

---

`data1` is a list of lists (of different length):

```
In [172]: data1 =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
In [173]: data1
Out[173]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

`arr1` is a 1d array containing 2 lists.  Note the `object` dtype:

```
In [174]: arr1 = np.array(data1)
In [175]: arr1
Out[175]: array([list([1, 2, 3, 4]), list([5, 6, 7])], dtype=object)
```

To get a 1d array of 7 numbers, we have to concatenate the sublists:

```
In [176]: np.hstack(data1)
Out[176]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

That operation is similar to a list join:

```
In [177]: data1[0] + data1[1]
Out[177]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

If the sublists have equal length then we can make a 2d array - with 2 rows and 4 columns, shape (2,4):

```
In [178]: data2 =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
In [179]: np.array(data2)
Out[179]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you please tell me how to create a row and column vector using numpy. I also want to use the transpose function of the row vector.

Comment: The last example has rows and columns. Follow the same pattern.  Also read up on `shape` and `reshape`